# Let $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are real polynomials, Why does $(x^2+y^2)p(x, y)^2\ne q(x, y)^2$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let  $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are real polynomials in $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p(x, y)\ne0$ and $q(x, y)\ne0$.

Why does $$(x^2+y^2)p(x, y)^2\ne q(x, y)^2$$ for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think you need a little care with the statement - the two sides of the equation aren't necessarily different for all $(x,y)$. However, you can prove that the two sides aren't equal as polynomials, which may be what you mean.

Comment: @πr8 - Thanks, Exactly, why does 'we can prove that the two sides aren't equal as polynomials'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ (the real polynomials) is what we call a *factorial ring* i.e. a ring where every $q\not=0$ can be decomposed uniquely as
$$
q=\lambda\prod_{i\in I} p_i^{\nu_i(q)}
$$
where $\lambda$ is invertible (here is a non-zero real) and $p_i$ is a complete family of irreducibles (see all standard texts). 
Now, $(x^2+y^2)$ is irreducible (one can choose it in the family) and 
$$
\nu_{(x^2+y^2)}[(x^2+y^2)p(x,y)^2]=2n+1
$$
whereas
$$
\nu_{(x^2+y^2)}[q(x,y)^2]=2m
$$
with $n,m$ integers, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the square root of both sides. There are some signs you need to think about, but basically can $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}p(x,y)$ ever be a polynomial for $p\ne 0\,?$

Answer (score 1):

Consider both sides of the equations as polynomials in $x$, and use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to factorise each side into linear factors of the form $(x-f_k(y))$.

Note then that the multiplicity of the factor $(x+iy)$ is odd on the left-hand side (one factor from $(x^2+y^2)$, plus double its multiplicity in $p$), but odd on the right-hand side (double its multiplicity in $q$). So we have a contradiction, and the two expressions cannot be equal as polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Assume equality holds, i.e.
$$(x^2 + y^2) p(x, y)^2 = q(x, y)^2$$
**Hint:** Can you make the LHS zero by choosing some $x$ and $y$? What would that mean for $q(x, y)$?

---

EDIT: Assuming you meant $p \neq 0$ and $q \neq 0$ as polynomial, as JLA points out in the comments, the hint above is not correct. Here is a slight alternative of Duchamp Gérard H. E.'s answer:

$r(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, so $q$ must have $r$ as a factor. Let $q = q_1r$, then
$$p^2 = rq_1^2.$$
Similar argument as before $p$ must have $r$ as a factor. Let $p = p_1r$, and we get
$$rp_1^2 = q_1^2,$$
an equation similar to the original, but $\mathrm{degree}(p_1) < \mathrm{degree}(p)$. This gives an [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) on the degree, a contradiction.

Comment: What is 'LHS zero'?Please more guide.

Comment: "Can you make the left-hand side of this equation equal to $0$ for some $x,y$?"

Comment: @πr8 Thanks, I was stumbling on what to say...

Comment: If I'm understanding your hint correctly then I suspect that you have misinterpreted the OPs question.

Comment: @JLA What do you mean? I am trying to show $p$ and $q$ are not equal as polynomials assuming both are non-negative.

Comment: Why are you assuming they are nonnegative though? I suspect this isn't what the OP meant.

Comment: @JLA Sorry, I mean't nonzero (everywhere). If OP meant they are not identically zero, then this my answer is not correct, I agree.

Comment: Yes but still, I don't think this is what the OP meant. I believe they meant not equal to 0 as polynomials.